# Layers hindering each other

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've tried looking up this issue earlier but I haven't stumbled upon anything I could fully grasp.

My problem is superficial: We are creating a small puzzle game which consists of a field(grid) and a layer below on which is being drawn. In XML it looks roughly like this:

```html
    <somethingsomething.DrawLine
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="324dp"
        android:layout_height="366dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-7dp"

        />
        
        <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:columnCount="9"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:rowCount="9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/corner_0_0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:minWidth="10dp" />
            
            ....
            ...
```

My class DrawLine relies on event input, like "is the screen being touched", whereas the many corners in the grid are "clickable". Due to these overlapping they hinder these events from occuring to the layer on bottom.

I need some way to merge the class in which I'm drawing a line with the grid above it.